# Did Maharshi Narada curse Lord Brahma?

Tags: puranas, brahma, curse, narada

When Lord Brahma cursed Narada Muni to become a Gandharva, did Narada curse him back?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism stack exchange, please try to add references to your claim.

Comment: @hanugm He is asking the source of the story. I have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Ha. I found some links online. Hoped that OP might update. Nice.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is available in the [narada charitra](https://kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/ESSENCE-OF-NARADA-CHARITRA.pdf). This is under the chapter mutual curses of Narada and Brahma.

> As Brahma allowed Sanaka Kumaras to carry on with their Tapasya and
> asked Narada to engage in ‘Srishti’ by becoming a house-holder,
> Narada’s reaction was instant and said : would there be a fool who
> would leave the outstanding ‘Amrit’ like ‘Seva’to Shri Krishna,
> instead of the poisonous drink of ‘Samsara’(family life) which is
> hopeless, illusory and distressful? As Narada dismissed Brahma’s
> proposal of Samsara with the least respect and consideration, the
> latter grew furious and visibly angry. **He cursed Narada** to become a
> quixotic, glibly and dreamy human being named ‘Upabarhana’ with
> frivolous nature, as an indulger in ‘Shringar’ (romance) and music, a
> veena player, talkative, wanderer and as the son of a servant maid;
> after repeated births would by the grace of Shri Krishna return to
> Brahma when he would then become a Gyani. **Narada was non-plussed by
> this spate of curses** and said: Your anger was least justified and
> unwarranted; normally, a father would chastise a son taken to wrong
> ways but in this case, many curses were hurled to a person with
> passion for the highest attachment and devotion for Shri Krishna!
>
> **Narada addressed Brahma Deva** as follows: ‘Chaturaanana! You have given
> me so many curses without justification for the only reason of not
> obeying you to distance myself from Paramatma and get into the
> whirlpool of Samsara! **I feel justified to give you too a few curses:**
> You will not be worshipped by anybody in the entire Universe by way of
> Stotra, Kavacha, Mantra and Puja for the next Three Kalpas; nor could
> be offered ‘Yagna Bhaga’(oblations at Yagnas through Agni Homas); You
> will also be denied worship by way of ‘Vratas’

Comment: Thanks so much

Comment: @Nayak, since the answer answers your question, you can accept by clicking (✔️) below the arrows on the answer. This means you accept it and it lets others know that this is the correct answer. Also please do contribute upvote since you liked the answer by pressing up arrow.